# Смена id объекта JS

Tags: javascript

Есть два объекта `input`

```
<input id="inp1" />
<input id="inp2" />
```

у них есть событие `oninput`

```
getInput.oninput = function() {
  if (document.activeElement == getInput) {
    sendInput.value = (getInput.value * courseInput.value);
  }
}

sendInput.oninput = function() {
  if (document.activeElement == sendInput) {
    getInput.value = (sendInput.value / courseInput.value);
  }
}
```

Так же есть кнопка(img) с событием `onclick`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ex.length; i++) {
  ex[i].onclick = function() {
    var temp = getInput.id;
    getInput.id = sendInput.id;
    sendInput.id = temp;
  }
}
```

Я хочу, что бы, по клику на кнопку, у `input` менялись `id` местами, это сейчас происходит, но события `oninput` продолжают работать как и работали, то есть визуально в разметке объекты местами поменялись, но события остались как прежде. Что нужно сделать, что бы событие следовали за `id`?

Comment: Ничего не понял...

Comment: @Air я тоже не понял, но догадался :)

Comment: _Что нужно сделать, что бы событие следовали за id?_ - нужно вместе с id присваивать и обработчики

Comment: @Grundy дело не только в обработчиках, но и во внешних переменных `getInput` и `sendInput`

Comment: @Igor, ага, не понял зачем вообще это условие внутри нужно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("inp1").oninput = recalculate;
document.getElementById("inp2").oninput = recalculate;

function recalculate()
{
  var getInput  = document.getElementById("inp1");
  var sendInput = document.getElementById("inp2");

  if (document.activeElement == getInput) {
    sendInput.value = (getInput.value * courseInput.value);
  } else if (document.activeElement == sendInput) {
    getInput.value = (sendInput.value / courseInput.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Понял.....)))))